# how to connect cassandra in thingboard running on Docker

Tags: docker, cassandra, thingsboard

I am using thingsboard (on docker) but I want also able to connect to the cassandra  on thingboard docker. What I want is checking table structure and data itself.

From the [reference installing thingboard on docker](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/docker/) run, there is no any -p 9042:9042 conifguration.

Therefore, I have added it to docker run command (eg. docker run  -p 9090:9090 -p 1883:1883 **-p 9042:9042** -p 5683:5683/udp -v /thingsboard/.mytb-data:/data.....  ). However, I cannot event telnet on 9042 to my main host.

Then, I checked cassandra configuration files in thingboard docker (/etc/cassandra). I have found that the value of **rpc_address** is localhost and there is no any line for **broadcast_rpc_address** . I am not sure what should I enter to the config file since it is a docker container.

Here are my port settings (I have added screenshot below):

```
0.0.0.0:1883->1883/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5683->5683/udp

CONTAINER ID -> ac2b6e2316a7 
IMAGE      -> thingsboard/tb-cassandra     
COMMAND    -> "start-tb.sh"    
PORTS      -> 0.0.0.0:1883->1883/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5683->5683/udp
```

[ports on docker run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1kYk.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As per the **thingsboard/tb-cassandra**'s [Dockerfile](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/master/msa/tb/docker-cassandra/Dockerfile), Cassandra is running on default configuration and listening on `localhost`. Thats why it's not accepting any connections from docker host machine.

In order to connect to Cassandra via `cqlsh` you need to login to the container using following command:

`docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash`

then you can connect to Cassandra by issuing `cqlsh` command.